# mysql subquery find fullname on 2nd table

Tags: mysql

I have this following two tables.

basically I need to match employee to user_hr table

Since user_hr has firstname and lastname two fields.. employee has fullname only 1 field

and i think joining them wont get me a result.

Table employee

```
id Fullname
1  ESTRELLADO, Jedidiah B.
2  Molano, Rodolfo B.
3  YU, Roxanne
```

Table user_hr

```
id Firstname   Lastname
1  Rodolfo     Molano
2  May         Rio
3  Jedidiah B  ESTRELLADO
```

I have a query that split fullname into lastname and firstname

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`FullName`, ',', 1), ',', -1) AS lastname,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`FullName`, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS firstname
FROM `employee`
```

or something like this

```
select FullName from employee
 where FullName 
in 
(
  select fullname from user_hr
)
```

What I want to do is to match the lastname firstname on my 2nd table

to be able to see result just like this.

```
Firstname   Lastname
Rodolfo     Molano
ESTRELLADO  Jedidiah B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Select 
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`e.FullName`, ',', 1), ',', -1) AS e.lastname,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`e.FullName`, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS e.firstname
 from employee e RIGHT JOIN user_hr u where e.lastname OR e.firstname =  e.Fullname
```

Comment: I mean except using id... i just want the lastname,firstname field